# how to use vimscript plugins with lua for neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I have some plugins that it's config use vim-script how can I config plugins that use vim-script with lua for neovim.

for example gruvbox use vim-script I look in docs for lua config but I didn't find any thing, I have to use vim-script to configure it.

Comment: Have you checked [nvim lua guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing your nvim stuff in lua, the `vim` object is automatically injected into your code by Neovim.
It allows getting and setting vim, plugins and variable related options in lua.

The gruvbox theme requires setting variables in the global scope. You can access the global scope using the `vim.g` field.

For example to set `g:gruvbox_bold` to 1, which is `true` in lua, you need to write

```lua
vim.g.gruvbox_bold = true
```

in your `init.lua` file.

I recommend you to take a look at this article.
https://www.notonlycode.org/neovim-lua-config/.
It is short and teaches the basics of using lua in Neovim.